# Complex filtering in rails app. Not sure complex sql is the answer?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, filtering

I have an application that allows users to filter applicants based on very large set of criteria. The criteria are each represented by boolean columns spanning multiple tables in the database. Instead of using active record models I thought it was best to use pure sql and put the bulk of the work in the database. In order to do this I have to construct a rather complex sql query based on the criteria that the users selected and then run it through AR on the db. Is there a better way to do this? I want to maximize performance while also having maintainable and non brittle code at the same time? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hazzit said, it is difficult to answer without much details, but here's my two cents on this. Raw SQL is usually needed to perform complex operations like aggregates, calculations, etc. However, when it comes to search / filtering features, I often find using raw SQL overkill and not quite maintainable.

The key question here is : can you break down your problem in multiple independent filters ? 
If the answer is yes, then you should leverage the power of ActiveRecord and Arel. I often find myself implementing something like this in my model :

```
scope :a_scope, ->{ where something: true }
scope :another_scope, ->( option ){ where an_option: option }
scope :using_arel, ->{ joins(:assoc).where Assoc.arel_table[:some_field].not_eq "foo" }
# cue a bunch of scopes

def self.search( options = {} )
  output   = relation
  relation = relation.a_scope if options[:an_option]
  relation = relation.another_scope( options[:another_option] ) unless options[:flag]
  # add logic as you need it
end
```

The beauty of this solution is that you declare a clean interface in which you can directly pour all the params from your checkboxes and fields, and that returns a relation. Breaking the query into multiple, reusable scopes helps keeping the thing readable and maintainable ; using a `search` class method ties it all together and allows thorough documentation... And all in all, using Arel helps securing the app against injections.

As a side note, this does not prevent you from using raw SQL, as long as the query can be isolated inside a scope.

If this method is not suitable to your needs, there's another option : use a full-fledged search / filtering solution like [Sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/). This uses another store, separate from your db, that indexes defined parts of your data for easy and performant search.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take that into advisement. I don't need to do any aggregation so the scope solution might work well for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this question fully without knowing more details, but I'll try anyway.

While databases are bad at quite a few things, they are very good at filtering data, especially when it comes to a high volumes.

If you do the filtering in Ruby on Rails (or just about any other programming language), the system will have to retrieve all of the unfiltered data from the database, which will cause tons of disk I/O and network (or interprocess) traffic. It then has to go through all those unfiltered results in memory, which may be quite a burdon on RAM and CPU.

If you do the filtering in the database, there is a pretty good chance that most of the records will never be actually retrieved from disk, won't be handed over to RoR and won't then be filtered. The main reason for indexes to even exist is for the sole purpose of avoiding expensive operations in order to speed things up. (Yes, they also help maintain data integrity)

To make this work, however, you may need to help the database a bit to do its job efficiently. You will have to create indexes matching your filtering criteria, and you may have to look into performance issues with certain types of queries (how to avoid temporary tables and such). However, it is definately worth it.

Having that said, there actually are a few types of queries that a given database is not good at doing. Those are few and far between, but they do exist. In those cases, an implementation in RoR might be the better way to go. Even without knowing more about your scenario, I'd say it's a pretty safe bet that your queries are not among those.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The situation I'm dealing with is that I have applicants who can fill out profiles consisting of 30 to 40 checkboxes. The users need to be able to filter applicants based on location and the criteria that the applicants entered. So in essence, a user would theoretically be able to search for all tutors that know spanish,german, and english who tutor math and science and who also do SAT test prep and they way I'm currently doing this is using logic to build complex sql statements. I'm wondering if this is the best solution for this particular problem.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a pretty normal scenario for filtering, so yes, I suggest to do it in SQL. You might be able to reduce complexity here and there by using RoR to avoid expensive joins (e.g. if you know that a certain subquery will only have one result, you might want to just do that as a separate query, thus reducing the complexity of the main query)